# Cutting Ceramic Glass Glazed Tile

Tags: ceramic-tile, cutting, backsplash

I have some glass glazed ceramic mosaic tile that I will soon install as our new kitchen backsplash.  The tiles are 4" x 4", with pre-scoring into 1" x 1" mosaics with a grout line of 1/16".  They are 3/8" thick.

I only have a wet tile saw at the moment.  The manufacturer recommends dry cutting these tiles.  What is the best way to cut them and minimise chipping of the glass glazed finish?

Many Thanks,

Simon

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the water pump on your wet tile saw and go ahead and use it. If you are worried about damaging your wet blade (I wouldn't be) you can buy a dry cut diamond blade for your wet saw.